# How to get a list of selected bones

Tags: scripting, rigging

How can I get a collection of two selected bones from an armature like the `bpy.struct.selected_objects[0]` list?

If I try this with bones I just get the armature objects name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your probably looking for [`bpy.context.selected_bones`](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_72_release/bpy.context.html#bpy.context.selected_bones)

Or ... `selected_editable_bones`

Comment: NameError: name 'selected_editable_bones' is not defined in 2.90

Answer (score 4):

You can use `bpy.context.selected_pose_bones` for bones in pose mode